# Git shows file as deleted when merging, but file is there in branch

Tags: git, merge

I have an issue which I can't explain. In branch 'release-14-5' I have a file EquityException.java which I clearly see and the file is there when I do clean copy of that branch (i.e. git clone, git pull)

But when I merge that branch to 'production' branch (which also contains the same file) I see that merge says file is deleted in branch 'release-14-5'

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): somefolder/EquityException.java deleted in release-14-5 and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of somefolder/EquityException.java left in tree.
```

How it can be if I clearly see that file in 'release-14-5' and even when I do compare in Intellij between 'production' and 'release-14-5' it says no differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to compare the two branch heads, `production` and `release-14-5`.

When you do a merge, the merge goes back to the ancestor point where the branches diverge. You can find out what that point is yourself:

```
git merge-base production release-14-5
```

The output of this command is the hash of the common ancestor commit.

Now carefully examine the log, on each branch, going back to this merge base point. You will likely find the answer why there is such a conflict. Quite probably, at least one of the two histories deleted the file and then put it back. (A useful question to investigate is: did the file exist at the merge base point?)

When Git merges branches, it individually considers all of the commits on both branches going back to the merge base; it doesn't just do a "three-way diff". So it can be tripped up by commits which delete a file which exists in both branches and at the merge base, even of subsequent commits restore the file.